# Why does a call to `fn pop(&mut self) -> Result<T, &str>` continue to borrow my data structure?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am developing some basic data structures to learn the syntax and Rust in general. Here is what I came up with for a stack:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
mod stack {
    pub struct Stack<T> {
        data: Vec<T>,
    }

    impl<T> Stack<T> {
        pub fn new() -> Stack<T> {
            return Stack { data: Vec::new() };
        }

        pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Result<T, &str> {
            let len: usize = self.data.len();

            if len > 0 {
                let idx_to_rmv: usize = len - 1;
                let last: T = self.data.remove(idx_to_rmv);
                return Result::Ok(last);
            } else {
                return Result::Err("Empty stack");
            }
        }

        pub fn push(&mut self, elem: T) {
            self.data.push(elem);
        }

        pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
            return self.data.len() == 0;
        }
    }
}

mod stack_tests {
    use super::stack::Stack;

    #[test]
    fn basics() {
        let mut s: Stack<i16> = Stack::new();

        s.push(16);
        s.push(27);

        let pop_result = s.pop().expect("");

        assert_eq!(s.pop().expect("Empty stack"), 27);
        assert_eq!(s.pop().expect("Empty stack"), 16);

        let pop_empty_result = s.pop();

        match pop_empty_result {
            Ok(_) => panic!("Should have had no result"),
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Empty stack");
            }
        }

        if s.is_empty() {
            println!("O");
        }
    }
}
```

I get this interesting error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:58:12
   |
49 |         let pop_empty_result = s.pop();
   |                                - mutable borrow occurs here
...
58 |         if s.is_empty() {
   |            ^ immutable borrow occurs here
...
61 |     }
   |     - mutable borrow ends here
```

Why can't I just call `pop` on my mutable struct?

Why does `pop` borrow the value? If I add a `.expect()` after it, it is ok, it doesn't trigger that error. I know that `is_empty` takes an immutable reference, if I switch it to mutable I just get a second mutable borrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `pop` function is declared as:

```
pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Result<T, &str>
```

Due to [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision), this expands to

```
pub fn pop<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Result<T, &'a str>
```

This says that the `Result::Err` variant is a string that lives as long as the stack you are calling it on. Since the input and output lifetimes are the same, the returned value might be pointing somewhere into the `Stack` data structure so the returned value must continue to hold the borrow.

> If I add a `.expect()` after it, it is ok, it doesn't trigger that error.

That's because `expect` consumes the `Result`, discarding the `Err` variant without ever putting it into a variable binding. Since that's never stored, the borrow cannot be saved anywhere and it is released.

To solve the problem, you need to have distinct lifetimes between the input reference and output reference. Since you are using a string literal, the easiest solution is to denote that using the `'static` lifetime:

```
pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Result<T, &'static str>
```

---

Extra notes:

- Don't call `return` explicitly at the end of the block / method: `return Result::Ok(last)` => `Result::Ok(last)`.
- `Result`, `Result::Ok`, and `Result::Err` are all imported via [the prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html), so you don't need to qualify them: `Result::Ok(last)` => `Ok(last)`.
- There's no need to specify types in many cases `let len: usize = self.data.len()` => `let len = self.data.len()`.

Comment: Does adding return changes anything? I do it for personal preference, as well as typing the variables so I know for now if I understand properly the return types.

Comment: @SamuelYvon no, none of my suggestions change anything. You can do whatever you want, but it's always **strongly recommended** to adhere to the coding conventions of the language you are in. Write Rust code like other Rust code, JS code like other JS code, Go code like other Go code, Ruby code like other Ruby code, etc.

Comment: I totally agree!

Answer (score 4):

This happens because of [lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html). When you construct a method which takes a reference the compiler detects that and if no lifetimes are specified it "generates" them:

```
pub fn pop<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Result<T, &'a str> {
    let len: usize = self.data.len();

    if len > 0 {
        let idx_to_rmv: usize = len - 1;
        let last: T = self.data.remove(idx_to_rmv);
        return Result::Ok(last);
    } else {
        return Result::Err("Empty stack");
    }
}
```

This is what compiler sees actually. So, you want to return a static string, then you have to specify the lifetime for a `&str` explicitly and let the lifetime for the reference to `mut self` be inferred automatically:

```
pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Result<T, &'static str> {
```